# My gas stove’s igniter never stops, the spark even starts before turning the knob

Tags: kitchens, appliances, stove, gas-burner

My gas stove’s igniter never stops, the spark even starts before turning the knob, so I had to unplug.
This is not igniter won’t stop when burner is lit, igniter just starts when I plug the code.

Comment: I take it the igniter isn't piezo then.  More details about the cooker would be useful.

Comment: Next morning, it just get it normal. I suspect I spilled some water or liquid when cooking or cleaning inside, and it did something, and dried overnight. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Please put that as an answer and accept it so others will know this is closed.